# How much memory is a block on the Wii?

Tags: nintendo-wii

I have an older Nintendo Wii that I would like to sell.  Before I can list it, I'd like to include how much memory the console has.  I searched Nintendo support and they said I could see this under Data Management.  However, when I go into that area, where the installed games are shown, I see "693 Blocks".  What does that mean?  Is there a different way I should use to determine how much memory the console has?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blocks was how Nintendo measured data for a while. There are calculators online like this one: https://nblocksconverter.herokuapp.com/mobile that show you that 1 block equals 0.125 MB.

Comment: Dang, so my unit has 1 GB of RAM?  I wonder if anyone would ever want to buy it...

Comment: How do you get to this conclusion? 693 free blocks would equal to 86 MB.

Answer (score 3):

Your unit doesn't have 1GB of RAM (as you assumed in your comment).

Every Wii has 512 MB of storage on a flash chip (some of which will be in use by the system itself) and 88 MB of RAM (24 MB fast 1T-SRAM and 64 MB slower GDDR3 SDRAM).

These 512 MB would equal to 4096 blocks. Your 693 blocks would then be equal to 86MB (1 block = 0.125 MB).

Comment: Got it.  So is the model I have one of the first ever released?